# RJSONIO & Google Geocoding Service to Geocode in R - Some minor issues

Tags: r, geocoding

This is a very simple geocoding example. However, this code when runs, throws warnings and data.json is empty -

```
data.json <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(url("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=india"))))
```

> Warning messages: 1: In if (is.na(encoding)) return(0L) :   the
>   condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>
> 2: In if (is.na(i)) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the
>   first element will be used

```
> length(data.json)

[1] 0
```

However, when I change the code and put the `readLines` block inside a `paste` block like this, it works:

```
> data.json <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(url("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=india")), collapse=""))
> length(data.json)

[1] 2
```

Why is this? What did `paste(..., collapse="")` did to get rid of the warnings and the data.json is complete.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you pass a vector of strings (one string for each line) to the `fromJSON` function, which expects a single string. It tries to process the first element, wich is not a complete JSON message: it does not work and there are a few warnings.

In the second case, you concatenate those lines into a single strings, and things work as expected.

Comment: Could be but then this should have worked  `code` library(RJSONIO)
  str <- gsub(' ','%20',"India")
  url <- paste('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=',str, sep="")
  response <- readLines(url, n=-1, warn="F")
  x <- fromJSON(response)